# Select only unique records

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all records in a table, but hide duplicate rows. So if 2 rows are completely the same (except for the auto increment ID of course), only 1 should be shown.

I thought this had to be done with distinct, but it still give me duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tbllulog
WHERE lulogluserial = $commandlu
ORDER BY `tbllulog`.`tbllulogid` DESC
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lulogtimestamp,
                lulogmoveemployee,
                lulogsource,
                lulogaction,
                lulogluoutput0status,
                lulogluinput0status
FROM tbllulog
WHERE lulogluserial = $commandlu
ORDER BY `tbllulog`.`tbllulogid` DESC
```

But this also give me duplicates

Anyone can point me out what i'm missing?

thanks!

Comment: Use `GROUP BY tbllulogid`

Comment: If the DISTINCT is not working then maybe you should look closely at those values. You may have trailing spaces or some over non obvious difference in the data.

Comment: lulogtimestamp... I would bet that one is probably not the same on all the rows you are selecting... timestamps usually aren't, unless you duplicate data by code.

Comment: Could you show the duplicate rows

Answer (score 2):

Use `DISTINCT` **and** `GROUP BY` and add the `tbllulogid` to the `SELECT`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT tbllulogid,
        lulogtimestamp,
        lulogmoveemployee,
        lulogsource,
        lulogaction,
        lulogluoutput0status,
        lulogluinput0status
   FROM tbllulog 
        WHERE lulogluserial = $commandlu 
        GROUP BY `tbllulog`.`tbllulogid` 
        ORDER BY `tbllulog`.`tbllulogid` DESC
```

Comment: Selecting values from a `GROUP BY` that are not a part of the grouping (or aggregate functions) gives undefined, and often surprising, results. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @type varchar(50);
DECLARE @num int;
SET @type = '';
SET @num  = 1;

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT lulogtimestamp,
       lulogmoveemployee,
       lulogsource,
       lulogaction,
       lulogluoutput0status,
       lulogluinput0status
       @num := if(@type = lulogmoveemployee, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
       @type := lulogmoveemployee As Dummy
FROM tbllulog
WHERE lulogluserial = $commandlu
ORDER BY `tbllulog`.`tbllulogid` DESC
) T WHERE row_number = 1
```